# Postman auto response

Tags: postman

I'm new with *Postman* and I don't know how should this be done (if applicable).

Is there a way in Postman to have it "auto response" if it received a request for a specific API (ex: return error 404)? In Fiddler this is called "Autoresponder" but I can't find any similar feature in Postman app.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Postman has a feature called as 'Mocks'.
In mocks, you can basically define a mock url and the response that it would send when somebody hits that URL.

For eg. your endpoint is: `/user/info` and method is 'GET'

Then you can define the mock to return a status code of `200` and response as `{ id: 1 }`

The mock url's are hosted by Postman itself and you can use it in your app / anywhere you like.

The docs around mocks are really helpful: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock_servers/intro_to_mock_servers/

---

***Additionally:***
In case you're using the desktop app for Postman (latest v7.0.6) then you can you take a real-time lesson tour to learn about Mocks in Postman.

*Steps to take the lesson:*

1. Click on 'Bootcamp' / 'Learn' (v6)

[image: Bootcamp Icon]

2. Click on 'Designing and mocking APIs'
   [image: Designing and mocking APIs]
3. There are two lessons which will run you through mocks - how to create and use them. You can try both of them.

[image]

Comment: I tried the "Mocks" of Postman but I think this won't do the thing I wanted. As I understand it the Postman will give a "mock" URL which return the response you specified. Anyway, I found that I can achieve what I want using Charles' Rewrite. For now I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Yeah, the mock url is given by postman but you can replace that mock url with your own server url once your development is done. What's your use-case exactly?

Comment: We have an iOS app that calls multiple API. We're trying to "block" one of the API and return specific error code when the iOS app send requests to that API. Postman able to "capture" all requests coming from the iOS app but can't do "auto response" to the said API.

Comment: Uhm, can you try importing this collection: https://www.getpostman.com/collections/e91265dca83b6e3192fd into postman and see how that can be done. 
-- 
Or, you can directly hit this url `https://d7e7ad11-36dc-4135-9fd0-11a2f47ce2db.mock.pstmn.io/getUser` and see how on hitting the `/getUser` endpoint, postman auto-responds with a 404 and error message also.


Isn't that what you need?

Comment: You can also update this mocked response anytime with whatever data you want to send on hitting the endpoint.